# Is signalR is for chat application website only?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, signalr

I found this [blog](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/370/Posts/9623/signalr-with-mvc3-chat-app-build-asynchronous-real-time-persistant-connection-websites.aspx) which is implementing signalr to asp.net mvc3.

Is there any function of signalr like real time `updating/reloading` a jqgrid?

**Scenario** for jqgrid

I have to PC. PC1 is for Client and PC2 is for Server. PC2 is already open the view`(included the jqgrid)` that he needed to confirm the request from the PC1. What my project is doing so far is when requesting from PC1 the view from PC2 is needed to be refresh in order see the requested data from PC1.

If signalr don't support this what else is the best way to achieve my problem?.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not only for chat.

> SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client.

That means that you can use this technology to make any web applications, which could benefit from real time communication between client and server. Chat is just an example of this kind of application.

You should be able to achieve your desired behaviour with SignalR, however detailed description on how to do this, is really outside of the scope of this answer.

Comment: can you give me some blogs that related to my problem?. Or is there any solution to it?

Comment: You should start with reading [official SignalR documentation](https://www.asp.net/signalr). Also I find posts [written by Scott Hanselman really helpful](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)

Comment: I've both links. in your 2nd link I am thinking how can i use it or modify/implement it in my current problem.